# Tutorial/Guide to create a classic, small Linux application in a package (Debian)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, package

I've made a small script in my machine, and an `alias` in `.bashrc` that calls it. It's a bash script with 3 lines, but it can grow.

Now, some people in my team found it useful, and want to use it.

Instead of saying "copy this alias, do this, do that, install that lib" I was thinking about creating a simple package to be a little more professional. Fact is, I've never done something like this before. And the problem to me is not creating a package, is trying to decide what usually do you put in a package.

Suppose I want to take my script, and create `myapplication`. I want to create a .deb file that my team would install and:

- Have a `/usr/bin/myapplication` or `/usr/sbin/myapplication` (what's the difference between them?), so they would just call `myapplication` at their terminal and it would work;
- Have a [man page](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm); (Where are usually located man pages in a debian system?);
- Have a possibility to read a `.myapplicationrc` in home folder with some configurations;
- Have an entry for shortcuts in a gnome installation (is it possible to have an universal shortcut "format" that's is available to KDE and Gnome as well?);
- Install dependencies.

I'm new to all that stuff. I usually code simple scripts and create an `alias` in my `bashrc`. I've never done a package before. Which guides do you know of that can help me accomplish what I thinking of above?

Comment: /usr/bin is for "user binaries" whereas /usr/sbin is for "user *system* binaries," a group of binaries that are meant for administrative tasks that users would typically not need. Your application would either go in /usr/bin or possibly in /opt/<your company>/bin.  See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a complete guide. I think the best thing to do is download a package that does exactly what I'm thinking of and do some reading, like [taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/).

Comment: The "new maintainer's guide" (as Rooke suggested) and the "policy manual" together with the "developers reference" are what you need to read (see https://www.debian.org/doc/ for more)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/index.en.html) is a place to start, though I welcome a more succinct answer.